# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' in API response sub model

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i am trying to get data from API. This problem occurs when I try to display data from the submodel of TravelStatus.dart. And i getting error like this

```
'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

this is my code to get data

```
List<dynamic> travel = [];
getTravel() async {
    String token = await getToken();
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/travel');
      final http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      });
      DMethod.printResponse(response);
      travel = jsonDecode(response.body)['group']
          .map((e) => TravelStatus.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print('terjadi kesalahan: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

this is **TravelStatus.dart**

```
class TravelStatus {
  final int id;
  final String travelStatus;
  final int userId;
  final int currentuser;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final DateTime updatedAt;
  final Travel travel;
  final Destination destination;
  final Acomodation acomodation;

  TravelStatus({
    required this.id,
    required this.travelStatus,
    required this.userId,
    required this.currentuser,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.travel,
    required this.destination,
    required this.acomodation,
  });

  factory TravelStatus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TravelStatus(
        id: json["id"],
        travelStatus: json["travel_status"],
        userId: json["user_id"],
        currentuser: json["current_user"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]).toLocal(),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]).toLocal(),
        travel: Travel(
          id: json['travel']['id'],
          reason: json['travel']['reason'],
          description: json['travel']['description'],
          organizationUnit: json['travel']['organization_unit'],
          tripAdvance: json['travel']['trip_advance'],
          tripExpense: json['travel']['trip_expense'],
          totalAmount: json['travel']['total_amount'],
        ),
        destination: Destination(
          id: json['destination']['id'],
          destination: json['destination']['destination'],
          start: json['destination']['start'],
          end: json['destination']['end'],
          transType: json['destination']['trans_type'],
          tripAdv: json['destination']['trip_adv'],
          curencyAdv: json['destination']['curency_adv'],
          locationTripAdv: json['destination']['location_trip_adv'],
          curencyLocation: json['destination']['curency_location'],
          meal: json['destination']['meal'],
          mealCurency: json['destination']['meal_curency'],
        ),
        acomodation: Acomodation(
          id: json['acomodation']['id'],
          checkIn: json['acomodation']['check_in'],
          checkOut: json['acomodation']['check_out'],
          location: json['acomodation']['location'],
          hotel: json['acomodation']['hotel'],
          curency: json['acomodation']['curency'],
          rateNight: json['acomodation']['rate_night'],
          total: json['acomodation']['total'],
          remarks: json['acomodation']['remarks'],
          billToCompany: json['acomodation']['bill_to_company'],
          chargeCode: json['acomodation']['bill_to_company'],
        ),
      );
}
```

this my model **Travel.dart**

```
class Travel {
    final int id;
    final String reason;
    final String description;
    final String organizationUnit;
    final String tripAdvance;
    final String tripExpense;
    final String totalAmount;


    Travel({
        required this.id,
        required this.reason,
        required this.description,
        required this.organizationUnit,
        required this.tripAdvance,
        required this.tripExpense,
        required this.totalAmount,

    });

    factory Travel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Travel(
        id: json["id"],
        reason: json["reason"],
        description: json["description"],
        organizationUnit: json["organization_unit"],
        tripAdvance: json["trip_advance"],
        tripExpense: json["trip_expense"],
        totalAmount: json["total_amount"],

    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "reason": reason,
        "description": description,
        "organization_unit": organizationUnit,
        "trip_advance": tripAdvance,
        "trip_expense": tripExpense,
        "total_amount": totalAmount,

    };
}
```

this my model **Destination.dart**

```
class Destination {
  final int id;
  final String destination;
  final String start;
  final String end;
  final String transType;
  final String tripAdv;
  final String curencyAdv;
  final String locationTripAdv;
  final String curencyLocation;
  final String meal;
  final String mealCurency;

  Destination({
    required this.id,
    required this.destination,
    required this.start,
    required this.end,
    required this.transType,
    required this.tripAdv,
    required this.curencyAdv,
    required this.locationTripAdv,
    required this.curencyLocation,
    required this.meal,
    required this.mealCurency,
  });

  factory Destination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Destination(
        id: json["id"],
        destination: json["destination"],
        start: json["start"],
        end: json["end"],
        transType: json["trans_type"],
        tripAdv: json["trip_adv"],
        curencyAdv: json["curency_adv"],
        locationTripAdv: json["location_trip_adv"],
        curencyLocation: json["curency_location"],
        meal: json["meal"],
        mealCurency: json["meal_curency"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "destination": destination,
        "start": start,
        "end": end,
        "trans_type": transType,
        "trip_adv": tripAdv,
        "curency_adv": curencyAdv,
        "location_trip_adv": locationTripAdv,
        "curency_location": curencyLocation,
        "meal": meal,
        "meal_curency": mealCurency,
      };
}
```

this my model **Acomodation.dart**

```
class Acomodation {
  final int id;
  final String checkIn;
  final String checkOut;
  final String location;
  final String hotel;
  final String curency;
  final String rateNight;
  final String total;
  final String remarks;
  final String billToCompany;
  final String chargeCode;

  Acomodation({
    required this.id,
    required this.checkIn,
    required this.checkOut,
    required this.location,
    required this.hotel,
    required this.curency,
    required this.rateNight,
    required this.total,
    required this.remarks,
    required this.billToCompany,
    required this.chargeCode,
  });

  factory Acomodation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Acomodation(
        id: json["id"],
        checkIn: json["check_in"],
        checkOut: json["check_out"],
        location: json["location"],
        hotel: json["hotel"],
        curency: json["curency"],
        rateNight: json["rate_night"],
        total: json["total"],
        remarks: json["remarks"],
        billToCompany: json["bill_to_company"],
        chargeCode: json["charge_code"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "check_in": checkIn,
        "check_out": checkOut,
        "location": location,
        "hotel": hotel,
        "curency": curency,
        "rate_night": rateNight,
        "total": total,
        "remarks": remarks,
        "bill_to_company": billToCompany,
        "charge_code": chargeCode,
      };
}
```

and **the log**

```
I/flutter (20850): Response: GET | http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/travel | 200
I/flutter (20850): {"group":[{"id":11,"travel_status":"Menunggu Persetujuan","user_id":0,"current_user":6,"created_at":"2023-06-12T03:05:53.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-06-12T03:05:53.000000Z","travel":[{"id":10,"document_date":null,"reason":"1","description":"1","organization_unit":"1","trip_advance":"1","trip_expense
I/flutter (20850): ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
I/flutter (20850): terjadi kesalahan: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

my **JSON response**

```
{
    "group": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "travel_status": "Menunggu Persetujuan",
            "user_id": 0,
            "current_user": 6,
            "created_at": "2023-06-12T03:05:53.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-06-12T03:05:53.000000Z",
            "travel": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "document_date": null,
                    "reason": "1",
                    "description": "1",
                    "organization_unit": "1",
                    "trip_advance": "1",
                    "trip_expense": "1",
                    "total_amount": "1",
                    "user_id": 6,
                    "travel_status_id": 11
                }
            ],
            "destination": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "destination": "2",
                    "start": "2",
                    "end": "2",
                    "trans_type": "2",
                    "trip_adv": "2",
                    "curency_adv": "2",
                    "location_trip_adv": "2",
                    "curency_location": "2",
                    "meal": "2",
                    "meal_curency": "2",
                    "user_id": 6,
                    "travel_status_id": 11
                }
            ],
            "acomodation": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "check_in": "3",
                    "check_out": "3",
                    "location": "3",
                    "hotel": "3",
                    "curency": "3",
                    "rate_night": "3",
                    "total": "3",
                    "remarks": "3",
                    "bill_to_company": "3",
                    "charge_code": "3",
                    "user_id": 6,
                    "travel_status_id": 11
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "travel_status": "Disetujui",
            "user_id": 0,
            "current_user": 6,
            "created_at": "2023-06-12T08:45:11.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-06-12T08:45:11.000000Z",
            "travel": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "document_date": null,
                    "reason": "1",
                    "description": "1",
                    "organization_unit": "1",
                    "trip_advance": "1",
                    "trip_expense": "1",
                    "total_amount": "1",
                    "user_id": 6,
                    "travel_status_id": 12
                }
            ],
            "destination": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "destination": "2",
                    "start": "2",
                    "end": "2",
                    "trans_type": "2",
                    "trip_adv": "2",
                    "curency_adv": "2",
                    "location_trip_adv": "2",
                    "curency_location": "2",
                    "meal": "2",
                    "meal_curency": "2",
                    "user_id": 6,
                    "travel_status_id": 12
                }
            ],
            "acomodation": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "check_in": "3",
                    "check_out": "3",
                    "location": "3",
                    "hotel": "3",
                    "curency": "3",
                    "rate_night": "3",
                    "total": "3",
                    "remarks": "3",
                    "bill_to_company": "3",
                    "charge_code": "3",
                    "user_id": 6,
                    "travel_status_id": 12
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' typically arises when you're trying to access an item from a list using a string as an index, or when you are trying to assign a String to an int variable or vice versa.

In your case, it seems like you're getting this error because the JSON response that you're trying to parse into your Acomodation class has some String values where int values are expected, or vice versa.

I can see that your Acomodation class has an id attribute that is an int. However, in the JSON response, it seems like the "id" value is a string. Also, you have other fields like rateNight, total which might be expected to be numbers (int or double) but coming as String from the response.

If you are expecting numeric values for those fields, make sure your backend API sends them as numbers, not strings. If you have no control over the backend API and the returned values will always be String, then you need to modify your model class to reflect this:

```
class Acomodation {
  final String id;  // change type from int to String
  final String checkIn;
  final String checkOut;
  final String location;
  final String hotel;
  final String curency;
  final String rateNight;  // if these are numeric values, change the type
  final String total;  // if these are numeric values, change the type
  final String remarks;
  final String billToCompany;
  final String chargeCode;

  Acomodation({
    required this.id,
    required this.checkIn,
    required this.checkOut,
    required this.location,
    required this.hotel,
    required this.curency,
    required this.rateNight,
    required this.total,
    required this.remarks,
    required this.billToCompany,
    required this.chargeCode,
  });

  factory Acomodation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Acomodation(
        id: json["id"].toString(),
        checkIn: json["check_in"],
        checkOut: json["check_out"],
        location: json["location"],
        hotel: json["hotel"],
        curency: json["curency"],
        rateNight: json["rate_night"],
        total: json["total"],
        remarks: json["remarks"],
        billToCompany: json["bill_to_company"],
        chargeCode: json["charge_code"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "check_in": checkIn,
        "check_out": checkOut,
        "location": location,
        "hotel": hotel,
        "curency": curency,
        "rate_night": rateNight,
        "total": total,
        "remarks": remarks,
        "bill_to_company": billToCompany,
        "charge_code": chargeCode,
      };
}
```

In this updated class, I changed the id from int to String and used json["id"].toString() in Accomodation.fromJson to make sure it is parsed as a string.

However, you should carefully check which fields are causing the problem in your particular case and set their types accordingly in your model class. Also, review your JSON response and compare it to your Dart models. To avoid such errors, make sure your data types match on both ends. If it doesn't work please get back to me

Comment: I have tried the solution you suggested but still the same problem occurs. I have also checked on the database all data is in the form of strings except id.

Comment: Some of your answers yesterday appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT) (the other is NAA, not-an-answer).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: Frankly, even if it was produced by artificial intelligence, I would not throw it here without checking it anyway. Please don't confuse me with others. Have a nice day !